# Проблема с кастомизацией infoWindow в Google Maps, ошибка: Uncaught mc, message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError"

Tags: google-maps

Пытаюсь добавить `infoWindow` над меткой в Google Maps.

Сам код:

```
function initMap() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.111939, 131.936366);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<table border = "0">'+
    +'<tr><td rowspan = "3"></td></tr>'+
    +'<tr><td>Режим работы</td><td></td></tr>'+
    +'<tr><td>Еще</td><td>wqe</td></tr></table>';


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Bahnhofstraße 32'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  // show map, open infoBox 
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Однако, стили метки не меняются, весь контент окна почему то превращается в **NanNanNanNan**, а в консоль выбивает:

> Uncaught mc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new mc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…591J_hdqav9LPA07faxn05jhk&callback=initMap:135:73"}

Если же вбивать просто текс \ параграфы и тд, то проблем нет. Как только кол-во текста в **contentString** становится чуть больше - все. А даже при меньших объемах текста стили не хотят подгружаться.

Мб кто сталкивался с такой бедой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сама суть проблемы не решена, почему стало так. 
Вместо стандартного infoWindow подключил infoBox.